# How to prove the accuracy of an OS files burn with dd from my PC to flash disk (for very old system)?

Tags: image, usb, iso, dd, clonezilla

I'm currently working with an older **Single Board Computer (SBC)** featuring an **i486 processor**, specifically the **Advantech PCM-3343 model**. My primary objective is to create a system image using Clonezilla. I've downloaded the **i486-compatible Clonezilla 2.2.2-32** ISO file and employed the dd command to make a bootable USB drive. The USB drive has been formatted with ext3 using `sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/sda1`.

However, I'm encountering difficulties booting Clonezilla, and it reports an error: "**unable to find a medium containing a live file system.**" To ensure the success of the dd command, I've compared the sizes of the ISO file and the USB drive using ls and df commands. The sizes seem appropriate.

Despite these efforts, the booting issue persists. I've checked the file system format with `sudo file -s /dev/sda1`, verified the presence of a boot loader, and confirmed an **MBR** partition table with `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`. Everything appears in order.

I'm open to alternative methods for creating a system image on this i486 system. If you have suggestions or insights on resolving the boot issue or if there's a different approach I could take, I'd greatly appreciate your guidance. Thank you for your assistance.

Also I tried to use different USB drives and different ports.